# How to send data to php file and return the value in javascript function?

Tags: php, javascript

In Js file I've created a function which has to send an id and return boolean value to php file which returns false or true; but how can I do it?

JS function

```
function findDB(id)
{

}
```

PHP side

```
include_once("kutuphane/inc.php"); 
$id = $_POST['tipi'];

$sql= "select count(id) from bolge_db where parent_id=$id"; 

    $faz2= $_SESSION["VT"]->doQuery($sql);

 $flag=false;
 if($faz2>0)
  {
    $flag= true;
  }
   else
  {
    $flag= false;
  }
```

Comment: AJAX is the solution, have a look at http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/

Comment: Please google SQL Injections. Your code is unsafe.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple AJAX! Try out this code in js:

```
function MakeRequest()
{
  var xmlHttp = getXMLHttp();

  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
    {
      HandleResponse(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
  }

  xmlHttp.open("GET", "ajax.php", true); 
  xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

keep in mind that you have to echo something in php! eg: echo 1; echo 0;

Answer (score 1):

Or using jQuery

```
var data = {
    var1 : "string or another var"
};

$.post('url.php',data , function(data) {
  var response = data;
  //Do What Ever You Want
});
```

Comment: My actual am is posting data to php and getting data from php. there I guess we can do it without function so $.post(url.php,data) is enough?

Comment: Yes it is, and you can grab data from PHP, but if you need a return statement than put $.POST inside the function end just return response.

Comment: so is it true in this way        $.post('dbController.php',cuIzgaraKay.id,function(cuIzgaraKay.id) {
  var response = cuIzgaraKay.id;

});

Comment: @user1702486 don't send the id directly you should send it as an Object $.post('dbController.php',{id:cuIzgaraKay.id},function(data) { var response = data; })